# Bootstrap table vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a few bootstrap table for my app but I was stacked on the vertical scroll. I can do it with the help of `overflow-y`, `display to block`, and `given height` and it scrolls as expected but the catch is when one of my table headers has few text character then it would not fill the entire table's width. I think I miss something in here. Please see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4pw5u73o/).

> Do I need to create another class to solve the issue of only one
>   table? or is there a better way to get this done.

HTML:

```css
.table-earnings {
  background: #F3F5F6;
}
table {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <table class="table table-earnings table-earnings__challenge">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>TITLE</th>
            <th>DATE TAKEN</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <th>AMOUNT</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Day 1</td>
            <td>11/08/2016</td>
            <td>
              <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>$1.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Day 1</td>
            <td>11/08/2016</td>
            <td>
              <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>$1.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Day 1</td>
            <td>11/08/2016</td>
            <td>
              <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>$1.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Day 1</td>
            <td>11/08/2016</td>
            <td>
              <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>$1.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Day 1</td>
            <td>11/08/2016</td>
            <td>
              <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>$1.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Day 1</td>
            <td>11/08/2016</td>
            <td>
              <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
            </td>
            <td>$1.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Wrapping your table in a div would solve your problem.

By default `table` takes `display:table`, in your code you are changing its natural behavior by changing its `display to block`. that absolutely will create mess.

```
.table-wrapper {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```css
.table-wrapper {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
.table-earnings {
  background: #F3F5F6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table class="table table-earnings table-earnings__challenge">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>TITLE</th>
              <th>DATE TAKEN</th>
              <th>STATUS</th>
              <th>AMOUNT</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Day 1</td>
              <td>11/08/2016</td>
              <td>
                <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
              </td>
              <td>$1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Day 1</td>
              <td>11/08/2016</td>
              <td>
                <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
              </td>
              <td>$1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Day 1</td>
              <td>11/08/2016</td>
              <td>
                <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
              </td>
              <td>$1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Day 1</td>
              <td>11/08/2016</td>
              <td>
                <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
              </td>
              <td>$1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Day 1</td>
              <td>11/08/2016</td>
              <td>
                <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
              </td>
              <td>$1.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Day 1</td>
              <td>11/08/2016</td>
              <td>
                <img src="https://www.srx.com.sg/srx/home/images/tracker/icon_social_sms.png" alt="">
              </td>
              <td>$1.00</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pw5u73o/2/)**

Comment: Man thanks it worked! Somethings missing in here. I just added `width: 100%;` to occupy the whole col.

Comment: With a `.table-responsive` table, I removed the `display: inline-block;` to have the full width.

Comment: Using a surrounding div worked, thanks!