# bootstrap table with vertical scrollbar visible

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I need to make a simple html page with bootstrap lib: my page has simply an header fixed to top and a table that may be long, so I need to scroll it... If I add simple a navbar and a table I obtain this:

[image: sample]

as you can see, the table is 'under' the navbar and I can't be able to scroll.. how can I do?

here is the example:

https://paste.ee/p/i1GnB

thank you

Comment: Post your [mcve] please

Comment: here is my page: https://paste.ee/p/i1GnB

Comment: Solution for the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40500949/10603429

Comment: Bootstrap 5.0 is still in beta, not for production websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see your header is fixed to the top and because that it's `going under the table` that you made. An `easy fix is just to add a padding-top to the table.` The amount of padding that you should add is `equal to the header's height` or more, try and see what you like more.